# Angular2: Passing multilevel object as route params

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I am working on a data list page that uses some filters (some select boxes with multiple value selection)

I need to be able to deep link this results so I need to pass all the params to the URL

if I pass a multilevel object (and not just key:value) pairs, I get [object Object] in the URL which is not good.

what would be the correct way to handle this? JSON.stringify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes `JSON.stringify` and [How to encode a query string so that it is the value of another query string in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/597028/how-can-encode-a-query-string-so-that-it-is-the-value-of-another-query-string-in) to make it a valid query value.

See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: Yeah, I thought so... I would have thought angular router would take care of it by default ;) Cheers! Btw... you are always so active and helpful on here... are you full time employed to offer the support here?

Comment: No, not employed to offer support. Just for fun and educational purposes :)

Comment: You should be. They should consider employ you and pay you nicely. You deserve it! Cheers